# Can I left join gracefully with Doctrine by checking id against null?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I have implemented the following function, which is very close to what I actually want:

```
public function loadUserGroupsOfNewsletter($ids, $newsletterID)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    return $qb->select('ug, gon')
              ->from('MyNameSpace:UserGroup', 'ug')
              ->leftJoin('ug.groupsOfNewsletter', 'gon')
              ->leftJoin('gon.newsletterItem', 'n')
              ->where($qb->expr()->in('ug.id', $ids))
              ->where('n.id = :id')
              ->setParameter('id', $newsletterID)
              ->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I would like to get at least a record for each user group. If there is no newsletter matching the id for a newsletter, then I would like `gon` to be `null` for the given result item, but if there is at least a newsletter matching the id, then I would like to have the correct user group and gon record in the result item.

So,

Case 1. The given user group does not have a matching newsletter:

The result item is expected to contain the correct `ug` and `null` as `gon`

Case 2. The given user group has at least a matching newsletter:

There are as many newsletter items as many such matches exist and all result items for this user group will contain valid `ug` and `gon`.

I have tried to check n.id against null and the results matched my expectation, so I assume that the following query achieves what I intended, due to the fact that my experiments yielded good results. Am I right in this assumption?

```
public function loadUserGroupsOfNewsletter($ids, $newsletterID)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    return $qb->select('ug, gon')
              ->from('MyNameSpace:UserGroup', 'ug')
              ->leftJoin('ug.groupsOfNewsletter', 'gon')
              ->leftJoin('gon.newsletterItem', 'n')
              ->where($qb->expr()->in('ug.id', $ids))
              ->where('(n.id is null) or (n.id = :id)')
              ->setParameter('id', $newsletterID)
              ->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, it *should* be fine, but I am not sure what are you trying to achieve by returning users both subscribed to this particular newsletter and those that are not subscribed **to any**?

You may try to to move those predicates to `IN` statement (`WITH` in `Doctrine`):

```
->leftJoin('ug.groupsOfNewsletter', 'gon')
->leftJoin('gon.newsletterItem', 'n', 'WITH', 'n.id = :id')
```

Does that make sense? Maybe I misunderstood you intention.

Another thing that caugth my eye is double use of `where`. According to `Doctrine`'s source, [where](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/41292e85dfadac771713882663ab5389e1070ecc/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L1058) looks like this:

```
public function where($predicates)
{
    if (! (func_num_args() === 1 && $predicates instanceof Expr\Composite)) 
    {
        $predicates = new Expr\Andx(func_get_args());
    }

    return $this->add('where', $predicates);
}
```

and [add](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/41292e85dfadac771713882663ab5389e1070ecc/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L672) has a following signature:

```
public function add($dqlPartName, $dqlPart, $append = false)
```

In other words, your subsequent `where` will not be appended but will overwrite the previous one instead.

You should probably use `andWhere` in order to do what you want.

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: I intend to render a table at the ui where the rows represent user groups (not users) which might be added to a newsletter and an add button for those, which are not added and a remove button for those, which are already added. So I need to get all available user groups, along with their possible corresponding groupsOfNewsletter record if it exists. Or, in other words, I intend to do something similar as the left join known in MySQL, that is, in the case when there is no match, the right side of the join will be filled with nulls.